# continue do in while loop when exception

Tags: c#

Why does this code continue to show a message when exception occurs?
It mean I want  complete all its Iterations even if there's any exception in any one of the iterations.

```
  private void cmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                int b = 10/i;
                MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
                i++;
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }      
    }
```

Comment: What is the _exception_ exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül A DivideByZeroException .. indefinitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> this code continues show a message when exception occurs

move `i++;` out of try-catch block. You don't increment it when you get an exception

```
while (i < 10)
{
    try
    {
        int b = 10 / i;
        MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: yes, i move but still not work

Comment: yes, this work. many tks